# Convert a NumPy array to a binary array with the condition of each element existing in a list

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Is there any way to convert an array to a binary array such that any element that exists within a defined list is 1, and any element not in the list is 0?

For example, if I define a NumPy array as so:

```
a = np.array([[23,43,1],[43,5,0],[5,0,0]])
```

and a list as so:

```
l = [5,43]
```

I want a function that converts the array to/creates this:

```
array([[0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0]])
```

I have already tried `np.where(a in l, 1, 0)`, and it gives me this error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
> ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isin.html

```
arr=np.array([[23,43,1],[43,5,0],[5,0,0]])
l = [5,43]
np.isin(arr, l).astype(int)
#array([[0, 1, 0],
#       [1, 1, 0],
#       [1, 0, 0]])
```